# 'magic.h' file not found?

Tags: python, command-line, python-magic

Attempting to use the [Panoptes client package](http://panoptes-python-client.readthedocs.io/) and installed
libmagic & magic after panoptes required. After configuring, I finally tried to run the command to upload my images:

```
panoptes subject-set upload-subjects -m image/jpeg 28014 manifest.csv
```

And received a long drawn out error, which started with

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/magic/__pycache__/_cffi__x7681a35x54cebdac.c:208:10: fatal error: 
      'magic.h' file not found
```

I attempted to uninstall and re-install libmagic & magic to solve the issue, to no avail. After restarting my process, I now have this error occur on the first command for panoptes:

```
panoptes configure
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can install python magic binary via pip

```
pip install python-magic-bin
```